# Is it possible to give the pipeline char '|' as a commandline argument?

Tags: shell

Is it possible to pass the pipeline character '|' as a commandline argument to a program rather than having it creating a pipeline between process a and b?

```
./program -a | -b .
```

I understand that it will be very confusing but I am wondering if you can somehow override this pipeline char not creating a pipe but just functioning as a normal char.

Comment: Just escape it from the shell's notice `./program -a \| -b .`

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: @msw I agree it's a close call, hence why I said "probably."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can escape any character in Bash-like shells with the `\` character so `./program -a \| -b` will pass the pipeline as a usual character.

In a batch file for windows I **think** you can do the same with the `^` character.

Comment: Your initial ^ is probbly windows isnt it! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Montaldo Just fixed that :)

Comment: Ah yes, great. Thanks

Comment: @Montaldo Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I will, just had to wait 10min :)

Answer (score 0):

```
./program -a \| -b .
```

or

```
./program -a '|' -b .
```

or

```
./program -a "|" -b .
```